# what is difference between cell value changing manually and with a control in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem in Excel 2010. The guys gave me codes before for monitoring a cell. when a cell (S3) is greater than 6 then another cell (S12) should be 7 and when (S3) come back to less than 7 then cell (S12) should be 21 .
cell (S3) is under control with a **Form Control** and we can not change it by manually. Two codes from guys are:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "S3" Then
    Me.Range("S12").Value = IIf(Target.Value > 6, 20, 7)

End If

End Sub
```

and second code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' run the code below only if a value in cell "S3" is changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S3")) Is Nothing Then

Select Case Target.Value ' <-- check the value of Range("S3")
    Case Is > 6
        Range("S12").Value = 20
    Case Else
        Range("S12").Value = 7
End Select

End If

End Sub
```

the problem is when I change S3 by **manually** then S12 follow that, but I change S3 by **Form Control** S12 does not change!

what is the solution?

any idea is appreciate ...

Kasra

Comment: Those bits of code, which are equivalent, will only be activated when S3 is manually changed. If it is changed by a formula you will need the `Calculate` event. (Not sure what you mean by 'control'.)

Comment: @SJR , S3 cell value has been change by a control. maybe some time it changes manually.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a formula in cell, instead of the macro code?

`: =IF(S3>6,"20","7")`

Comment: Incidentally, when I use a Macro then the codes work and also when I change S3 value manually.
My problem is when I try to change S3 by a Form Control  or Active X Control the codes do not work.

Comment: As a reply to your idea, I can't use a formula in S12, cause some time I should put a value in S12 manually . So when I put a value in S12 then I lost the formula.